# ASP.NET Application has incorrect CurrentCulture - en-CA instead of en-US

Tags: c#, asp.net, globalization, cultureinfo

I have an ASP.NET Application that I migrated to a new server. I made an effort to, as closely as possible, duplicate the old web servers settings.

However, the application is now throwing up datetime.tryparse exceptions on our calendar controls.

The **UICulture is set to en-US**

The **TryParse() methods are specifying en-US explicitly**

The **Culture seems to be defaulting itself to en-CA.**

The IIS web configs haven't changed (they are default) and the server's language settings are set to en-US.

**Is there a place I am failing to check for a culture setting?** I had a look at [this stack thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11135002/currentculture-incorrectly-defaulting-to-en-us-in-asp-net) but nothing immediately jumped out at me.

Is forcing a culture via the web config the only resolution here? Surely I must have failed to check a spot for an accidental setting of en-CA?

Comment: You could set the [`DefaultThreadCurrentCulture `](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.defaultthreadcurrentculture%28v=VS.110%29.aspx). What is used in your regional options control panel?

Comment: Yes, that would be a valid solution. Is ThreadCurrentCulture different from the two culture properties I mentioned? Or are they related?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into similar issues with our environment where our server machine was running Windows Server 2008 R2 and after struggling we managed to figure out where the Current Thread was reading the culture from.

If you navigate in the registry to the following path

```
HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Control Panel\International
```

You will see that it is probably set to something that you do not want. If for example you would like to change it to "en-CA" you will need to change the current registry values to the following:

```
Locale: 00001009
LocaleName: en-CA
sCountry: Canada
sLongDate: MMMM-dd-yy
sShortDate: dd/MM/yyyy
sYearMonth: MMMM, yyyy
```

Once these registry values have been changed, the machine will require a reboot.

Hope this helps you as much as it helped us in solving our problem.

Answer (score 1):

adding in your `web.config` this is totally legit if you want your site to run always in this culture:

```
<system.web>
....
<globalization culture="en-US" uiCulture="en-US"  enableClientBasedCulture="false"  />
```

it is the same as set in you code DefaultThreadCurrentCulture.

Anyway I can bet that:

or in your [server's machine.config](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229697%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) culture is set as "en-CA"

or your calendar control (probably a javascript one) is loading the clientculture. You can check this looking at your browser default language settings.

Comment: Could this be a registry issue do you think? Maybe .NET is looking a registry entry that isn't being updated correctly?

Comment: @Ray no registry! maybe machine.config or your calendarcontrol javascript