# Where System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture is set

Tags: c#, asp.net

Where is System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture set?  I have a US customer (and I am in US); the debugging code shows the value equals "en-GB".  And therefore dates are shown in British format ('DD/MM/YYYY').  Where is this set, in which file?

Comment: Is this on a web page? It should be set by the user-agent (aka, the browser)

Comment: Whatever @Flydog57 said... except "**could** be set by the user-agent". Obviously without knowing at least what you are debugging (based on "asp.net" tag it could be a web site, but many questions tagged as "asp.net" with intention "written in C#") and how whatever code is configured...

Comment: Yeah, **_could_** be set.  If you have access to the logs, I'm pretty sure you should see the user-agent string there (sorry, it's been a log time since I waded through logs like that)

Comment: Most likely, it's set on the client machine's OS; if it's Windows 10, ask your client,if possible, to run `Get-Culture` command in PowerShell - chances are, it's *en-GB*

Comment: This is a ASP.NET application; web site.  The app is running on a Server 2016.  I see this setting when I connect to the server via Remote Desktop. And one of the clients see it in her browser.  I have a setting in my program that uses CODE when calling SQL Select (SQL Server).  And the code depends on the culture. It is "103" for 'en-GB' and '111' for 'en-US'.  This works well on my PC and on other customers.  I will follow all your suggestions.  Thank you all.

Comment: You can force by https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentuiculture?view=netstandard-2.0 and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture?view=netstandard-2.0

Comment: @donggas90  Thank you very much. Your link helped to force the culture to the US.
I don't know how to give you the solution though.  Let me know, please.

Comment: I posted answer with more informations. If you solved the issue, please mark the answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CurrentCulture incorrectly defaulting to en-US in ASP.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11135002/currentculture-incorrectly-defaulting-to-en-us-in-asp-net)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can force current `CultureInfo`s by [CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentuiculture?view=netstandard-2.0) and [CultureInfo.CurrentCulture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture?view=netstandard-2.0).

The first one effects to text based things such like datetime etc. The second one effects to numbers such like floating points. Setting both to same `CultureInfo` is basic implement.

Note that, this will work fine if you don't consider multi-languages. Or you need to add language selecting menus.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, `CultureInfo` comes from the OS (presuming it's not explicitly overridden in code); in case of a web application, `CultureInfo` *typically* comes from the *client OS*, via HTTP's `Accept-Language` header (you can likely monitor this with tools like Fiddler, etc).

In your case, if it's possible to ask the client to check their system setting - on Windows 10, the PowerShell command `Get-Culture` will return the current culture set in the OS, for instance - you might be able to determine the source of the problem.

Furthermore, it is possible to set a different culture for the current user (no Admin required, I believe), using the PowerShell `Set-Culture -CultureInfo en-US` command, where *en-US* is the desired culture (no pun intended). There is also a way to reset it for the entire machine, with the PowerShell `Set-WinSystemLocale -SystemLocale en-US` command (Admin rights and a reboot are required).

Comment: I will ask the customer IT to run PowerShell.  This is Server 2016.

Comment: The system accessing your ASP.NET application is Server 2016? Your server is very likely set to `en-US`, but is not really relevant for determining client-side culture in a typical web app setup. Either way, same PowerShell commands should work on Server 2016, if you want to check; be careful with any `Set` commands though.